# how to keep folded functions folded when I open my .R file on another device. rStudio

Tags: r, function, rstudio, environment, fold

I m going to email my .R codes.
it would be great if my receiver can also open .R file and get my folded functions folded. ( neat and readable )

how is this achieved in Rstudio?

Comment: If you want to suggest features for RStudio a better place would be [their own community site](https://community.rstudio.com/) or their [github issues](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues). R files are just text files. There's not really anywhere to store the "state" of folded elements when sending such a file to other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [code folding in Rstudio](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200484568-Code-Folding-and-Sections-in-the-RStudio-IDE)

> Folded regions are preserved while editing a document; **however all foldable regions are shown expanded by default when a file is closed and re-opened.**

But, we can use short-cuts as mentioned in the post if we want to expand all/collapse all

> Edit -> Folding:

> Collapse — Alt+L

> Expand — Shift+Alt+L

> Collapse All — Alt+O

> Expand All — Shift+Alt+O

Comment: hmm, :(. It would be of HUGE help in terms of reading code more efficiently, if Rstudio group add such property to keep folded regions folded. thank you @akrun!

Comment: There should be some cookies that should keep a memory of the files earlier loaded and folded to keep it in folded case when it is reloaded.

Comment: It would be great to set one of these options as a default.